# Can't suggest an edit to a tag wiki: "The edit queue is full at the moment" error message is always shown even if the edit review queue is clear

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

More than 12 hours ago, I tried to create a tag wiki for the [poker-face](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poker-face) tag but encountered an error message:

> The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!

I tried again in a few minutes but got the same error message. I checked the suggested edits review queue and found out that it's clear - with nothing to review, unlike what the error message says. I assumed it was a temporary issue.

More than 12 hours later, I tried to create the tag wiki again but got the same error message, and the suggested edits review queue remains clear.

Update: A day later, the issue still persists.

Comment: Such issues are almost always a SE-wide problem. Best to check their meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387154/it-is-now-impossible-to-make-a-suggested-edit-to-a-tag-info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report - this was also raised and addressed on on SE-wide meta

**See**: [It is now impossible to make a suggested edit to a tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387320/209031)